# Determine leftmost operand when overloading __concat

Tags: lua

Is it possible to determine the leftmost operand when overloading right associative operators internally? Something along the lines of this.

```
MyClass.__concat(left, right)
  if is_leftmost_operand(left) then
    -- do stuffs
  else
    -- do other stuffs
  end
end
```

Where you'll call add as you normally without setting some kind of flag or something.

```
instance1..instance2..instance3
```

I want the right associative behavior of `__concat` but I want something different to happen when at the start of the chain.

EDIT:

To clarify, in the following expression `instance1` and `instance3` will both be considered the leftmost operand.

```
instance1..instance2..(instance3..instance4..instance5)
```

Comment: Should `c` be considered as leftmost in expression `a..b..(c..d..e)`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes, a and c would both be.

Comment: IMO, there is no way to distinguish leftmost operand without modifying Lua sources.

Answer (score 1):

Before I go into this, I would *strongly* suggest using an additional operation for whatever special you intend to do with the leftmost operator. `__unm` or `__len` would be obvious choices as they are unary. So for example your statement could look like

```
local x = -(a .. b .. c)
```

This would make your code a lot better to follow, as otherwise your concatenation operations will not be substitutable and also lose associativity of the default `..` operator. What I mean is, with your intended operation these equations would be true:

```
a .. b .. c ~= a .. (b .. c)
(a .. b ) .. c ~= a .. (b .. c)
```

Having said that: I do not think you can detect the leftmost operation in Lua - at least before the assignment, but you can *kind of* detect the **rightmost** operation.

Since you did not write exactly *what* you intend to do, I would just point out that probably your operation can be changed around so that you handle the rightmost operation differently and get the same result in the end, so here's some sample code

```
local MT = {};
local registry = setmetatable({}, {__mode == "k"});

function MT.__concat(left, right)
    if not registry[right] then
        print("rightmost operation", left, right);
    end

    local r = newTT(left.val .. right.val);
    registry[r] = true;

    return r;
end

function MT:__tostring()
    return tostring(self.val);
end

function newTT(v)
    return setmetatable({ val = v }, MT);
end

local a = newTT("A");
local b = newTT("B");
local c = newTT("C");
local d = newTT("D");

local x = a .. (b .. c) .. d;
local y = a .. (c .. b) .. d;
local z = a .. b .. x; -- the b .. x op will not be detected as rightmost!
```

You could probably work around the problem I pointed out in the last line by resetting the registry on each tick, but actually that behavior would make the operation more predictable. Or at least in my eyes.

Well anyway, you can see that doing such things introduces a whole bunch of new problems that are very probably not worth the effort they take to resolve.

Comment: Nice idea to manually mark leftmost operator with `-`.  Extra parentheses are not needed: in `-a..b..c` object `a` will be converted to marked object `-a` before concatenation, it's OK.

Comment: `-a..b..c` would be same as `(-a)..b..c` though. Since my intention was to do an operation on the resulting object after all the concatenation operations, as I thought this was most likely what the OP wanted to do... Your variant would work too of course, no doubt about that.